# docker run image causes syntax error /bin/sh

Tags: image, docker, syntax

When I run docker command on my image, it errors out. Any ideas on what should I include in my Dockerfile for CMD? Currently I have `java -jar my.jar` in it.

```
docker run startlog
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: You need to provide us with more details on the contents of your Dockerfile in order for us to help. Also the output you have provided shows that there is a unterminated quoted string some where. Have you checked your Dockerfile that everything is terminated OK?

Comment: FROM openjdk:8
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/startlog/
ADD gs-rest-hateoas-0.1.0.jar /tmp/startlog/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", “/tmp/startlog/gs-rest-hateoas-0.1.0.jar"]

Answer (score 8):

From your comment (this should really be an edit to your question):

```
FROM openjdk:8
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/startlog/
ADD gs-rest-hateoas-0.1.0.jar /tmp/startlog/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", “/tmp/startlog/gs-rest-hateoas-0.1.0.jar"]
```

you do not have a double quote in front of `/tmp/startlog`, instead you have a "smart quote" which is invalid for programming. Please ditch whatever editor created that and don't use it for any more coding.

What happened with the smart quote is that the entrypoint json was not valid json, so it gets run as

```
/bin/sh -c '["java", "-jar", “/tmp/startlog/gs-rest-hateoas-0.1.0.jar"]'
```

And before /bin/sh looks for the command `["java",` it sees a parsing problem with the unmatched quotes.

Comment: This fixed my issue aswell, thanks. Now i just wonder how the hell that smart quote got into my dockerfile.

Comment: I hope it was not the editor, your editor should not be reformatting things like quotes. It could however be a copy-paste issue.